# Always know whether checkbox is/was checked or not

Tags: html

My webpage looks like this

```
<form id="1" ... action="<?php $arr = explode ('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); echo $arr[count($arr) - 1]; ?>#partone">       
  <div id = "partone">Hello</div>
</form>

<form id="2" ... action="<?php $arr = explode ('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); echo $arr[count($arr) - 1]; ?>#parttwo">       
<?php
if(//what?)
  echo '<input type="checkbox" name="aktualisieren" value="yes" id="aktualisieren" checked>refresh';
else
  echo '<input type="checkbox" name="aktualisieren" id="aktualisieren" value="no">refresh';
?> 
<div id = "parttwo">Hello, two</div>
</form>
```

My goal is to

- always know whether checkbox *aktualisieren* is checked/was checked before page was submitted
- transfer the state
- save the state to a variable $checked

So if *aktualisieren* was checked, it should be checked now and some variable $checked should be true and vice versa for unchecked.

A problem occurs when *form 1* is submitted while *form 2* contains the checkbox, so there will be no field in $_POST for checkbox then.

**EDIT:** The reason for using different forms is that I want to submit it with different anchors to jump to the appropriate position based on where it was submitted. If that can be done differently, I can use only one form.

Comment: Maybe you could use some JavaScript (like http://flesler.blogspot.cz/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) to do that, before you do horrible things to both your HTML code and your users?

Answer (score 1):

Use **a single form**. This is the answer on how to do it.

Otherwise you have to use a tiny *hack* to do it:
Create the same checkbox-element within form1, but hide it. Whenever the checkbox's state in form1 is changed you have to change the state of the hidden checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You shall always use only a one form per page. Otherwise, when you submit one form, all data from other form are lost. I usually start the form at the very start of the body tag.